# Преобразовать уникальные строки в уникальные числа (factorization) в Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть набор данных в котором содержится поле 'Country'.Количество уникальных значений более 100. Как присвоить каждой стране соответствующий уникальный номер?

```
      Measure           Country             Citizenship  Year    Value
0            0           Oceania     New Zealand Citizen  1979  11817.0  
1            0           Oceania      Australian Citizen  1979   4436.0  
2            0           Oceania  Total All Citizenships  1979  19965.0  
3            0        Antarctica     New Zealand Citizen  1979     10.0  
4            0        Antarctica      Australian Citizen  1979      0.0  
5            0        Antarctica  Total All Citizenships  1979     13.0  
6            0    American Samoa     New Zealand Citizen  1979     17.0  
7            0    American Samoa      Australian Citizen  1979      4.0  
8            0    American Samoa  Total All Citizenships  1979     30.0  
9            0         Australia     New Zealand Citizen  1979   8224.0  
10           0         Australia      Australian Citizen  1979   4092.0  
11           0         Australia  Total All Citizenships  1979  13037.0  
12           0     Cocos Islands     New Zealand Citizen  1979      0.0  
13           0     Cocos Islands      Australian Citizen  1979      0.0  
14           0     Cocos Islands  Total All Citizenships  1979      0.0  
15           0      Cook Islands     New Zealand Citizen  1979    317.0  
16           0      Cook Islands      Australian Citizen  1979      5.0  
17           0      Cook Islands  Total All Citizenships  1979    807.0    
18           0  Christmas Island     New Zealand Citizen  1979      0.0  
19           0  Christmas Island      Australian Citizen  1979      0.0  
20           0  Christmas Island  Total All Citizenships  1979      0.0  
21           0              Fiji     New Zealand Citizen  1979    358.0  
22           0              Fiji      Australian Citizen  1979      9.0  
23           0              Fiji  Total All Citizenships  1979    680.0  
24           0        Micronesia     New Zealand Citizen  1979      2.0  
25           0        Micronesia      Australian Citizen  1979      0.0  
26           0        Micronesia  Total All Citizenships  1979      4.0  
27           0              Guam     New Zealand Citizen  1979      0.0  
28           0              Guam      Australian Citizen  1979      0.0  
29           0              Guam  Total All Citizenships  1979      1.0  
...        ...               ...                     ...   ...      ...  
86496        2          Tanzania     New Zealand Citizen  2016      4.0  
86497        2          Tanzania      Australian Citizen  2016      0.0  
86498        2          Tanzania  Total All Citizenships  2016     16.0  
86499        2            Uganda     New Zealand Citizen  2016      8.0  
86500        2            Uganda      Australian Citizen  2016      0.0  
86501        2            Uganda  Total All Citizenships  2016     14.0  
86502        2       South Yemen     New Zealand Citizen  2016      0.0  
86503        2       South Yemen      Australian Citizen  2016      0.0  
86504        2       South Yemen  Total All Citizenships  2016      0.0  
86505        2             Yemen     New Zealand Citizen  2016      0.0  
86506        2             Yemen      Australian Citizen  2016      0.0  
86507        2             Yemen  Total All Citizenships  2016      6.0  
86508        2           Mayotte     New Zealand Citizen  2016      0.0  
86509        2           Mayotte      Australian Citizen  2016      0.0  
86510        2           Mayotte  Total All Citizenships  2016      0.0  
86511        2      South Africa     New Zealand Citizen  2016     53.0  
86512        2      South Africa      Australian Citizen  2016      4.0  
86513        2      South Africa  Total All Citizenships  2016   4297.0  
86514        2            Zambia     New Zealand Citizen  2016     -4.0    
86515        2            Zambia      Australian Citizen  2016      0.0  
86516        2            Zambia  Total All Citizenships  2016     19.0  
86517        2          Zimbabwe     New Zealand Citizen  2016      4.0  
86518        2          Zimbabwe      Australian Citizen  2016      2.0  
86519        2          Zimbabwe  Total All Citizenships  2016     63.0  
86520        2        Not stated     New Zealand Citizen  2016    908.0  
86521        2        Not stated      Australian Citizen  2016     80.0  
86522        2        Not stated  Total All Citizenships  2016   3177.0  
86523        2     All countries     New Zealand Citizen  2016  -1818.0  
86524        2     All countries      Australian Citizen  2016   3487.0  
86525        2     All countries  Total All Citizenships  2016  70588.0  

[86526 rows x 5 columns]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример DataFrame в __текстовом__ виде, чтобы его можно было скопировать (врядли кто-то захочет набирать текст с картинки) и выходной/ожидаемый DataFrame (в любом читаемом виде - текст, картинка, etc.), чтобы было понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать...

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Пока не понятно что значит `причисления порядкового номера каждой отдельной строке в данном датасете` - просто пронумеровать все строки как в индексе или "факторизировать" `Country` так чтобы каждому уникальному названию соответствовало уникальное число? ?

Comment: @MaxU, да, чтобы каждому уникальному названию соответствовало свое уникальное число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
In [17]: df['CountryID'] = pd.factorize(df.Country)[0]

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
    Measure         Country             Citizenship  Year    Value  CountryID
0         0         Oceania     New Zealand Citizen  1979  11817.0          0
1         0         Oceania      Australian Citizen  1979   4436.0          0
2         0         Oceania  Total All Citizenships  1979  19965.0          0
3         0      Antarctica     New Zealand Citizen  1979     10.0          1
4         0      Antarctica      Australian Citizen  1979      0.0          1
5         0      Antarctica  Total All Citizenships  1979     13.0          1
6         0  American Samoa     New Zealand Citizen  1979     17.0          2
7         0  American Samoa      Australian Citizen  1979      4.0          2
8         0  American Samoa  Total All Citizenships  1979     30.0          2
9         0       Australia     New Zealand Citizen  1979   8224.0          3
..      ...             ...                     ...   ...      ...        ...
50        2          Zambia  Total All Citizenships  2016     19.0         16
51        2        Zimbabwe     New Zealand Citizen  2016      4.0         17
52        2        Zimbabwe      Australian Citizen  2016      2.0         17
53        2        Zimbabwe  Total All Citizenships  2016     63.0         17
54        2      Not stated     New Zealand Citizen  2016    908.0         18
55        2      Not stated      Australian Citizen  2016     80.0         18
56        2      Not stated  Total All Citizenships  2016   3177.0         18
57        2   All countries     New Zealand Citizen  2016  -1818.0         19
58        2   All countries      Australian Citizen  2016   3487.0         19
59        2   All countries  Total All Citizenships  2016  70588.0         19

[60 rows x 6 columns]
```